# Trying to add contact form

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Been working on this a bit and somewhat dificult with my limited skills. I created the area so far but adding the contact form is proving to be a huge challenge for me.

This is the area so far:
[image]

The grey area is where I would like the contact form to go, something like this:
[image]

What I would like the contact form to achive:

1. Add the (Ask a Question)
2. Person using contact form has to input Name,email, and telephone before contact agent button allows to be sent.
3. Info box to default message: I'm interested in the Post address but they can always override by typing in their own message.
4. Contact message will be sent to whatever the above email address is populated (right now it's mine up there joe@teamambrose.realtor
5. below the Contact Agent button show: By sending a request you agree to our Privacy Policy.

Here is where I am so far on the code:

```html
<!--======= Agent Info =========-->
   <section class="info-property agents-info">
    
    <h5 class="tittle-head"><?php esc_html_e('agent details', 'realtor');?></h5>
    <div class="inner"> 
     
     <!--======= AGENT DETAILS =========-->
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
       <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image(_sh_get_attachment_id_from_src(sh_set($meta1, 'agent_img')), '270x288');?>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
       <?php $term_list = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_id(), 'property_agent', array("fields" => "names")); ?>
       <h5><?php echo implode( ', ', (array)$term_list );?></h5>
       <!--======= SOCIAL ICONS =========-->
       <ul class="social_icons">
        <li class="facebook"><a href="<?php echo sh_set($meta1, 'facebook_link');?>"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
        <li class="twitter"><a href="<?php echo sh_set($meta1, 'twitter_link');?>"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
        <!--<li class="googleplus"><a href="<?php echo sh_set($meta1, 'google_plus_link');?>"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>-->
        <!--<li class="linkedin"><a href="<?php echo sh_set($meta1, 'linked_in_link');?>"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>-->
        <li class="instagram"><a href="<?php echo sh_set($meta1, 'instagram_link');?>"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
       </ul>
       <p><?php $description = $agents_term[0]->description; echo $description;?></p>

       <!--======= AGENT INFOR =========-->
       <ul class="agent-info">
        <li>
         <p><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> <?php echo sh_set($meta1, 'phone');?> </p>
        </li>
        <li>
         <p><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i><span style='font-size:11px'><?php echo sh_set($meta1, 'email');?></span></p>
        </li>
        <li>
         <p><i class="fa fa-home"></i> <?php printf( esc_html__('Listed %s Properties', 'realtor'), sh_set(sh_set($agents_term, 0 ) , 'count' ) );?> </p>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="overlay">
                  <div class="container">
                   <h1><?php echo balanceTags($title);?></h1>
       <div class="pull-left"><?php echo balanceTags($title);?> </div>
       <h5>
       <div style="text-align: center;">
           <?php echo 'Learn More: ' . get_the_title();?> </div>
       </h5>
            </div>
                 </div>
        
     <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
             <div style="height: 400px; width: 300px; background-color: #f8f8f8; border: 1px solid #dddddd;">
                            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
          <div style="max-height: 400px; overflow: hidden; max-width: 610px; padding-left: 43px;">
          <?php the_post_thumbnail('337x271', array('class' => 'img-responsive', 'style' => 'transform: translate(0%, -10%)'));?>
       </div>
         </div>
        </div>
   </section>
```

Any help on this will be awesome!

Comment: *"... is proving to be a huge challenge ..."* is not a specific question; where are you stuck?

Comment: ..and why not using an existing form plugin?

Comment: Majid I am just a weekend warrior with this my skills are mediocre at best, trying to implement something similiar to this in the grey box area I created https://www.sitepoint.com/build-your-own-wordpress-contact-form-plugin-in-5-minutes/

Comment: Phillip, don't want to use a plugin, once I get on the right track styling I can handle myself and feel being I created the area can have enough of a start to style on my own. Also only need it in this unique instance and always try to keep the fat down by adding to many unnecessary plugins.

Comment: So you already linked a tutorial.. any problems implementing your own form that way?

Comment: going to be a lot of trial and error for a hack like me 10-15 hrs worth.

Comment: Use a plugin. I am not a weekend warrior, and I respect your comments on keeping the fat down, that being said, dealing with user input is a dangerous thing for the inexperienced and trying to implement it inside of an already complex and convoluted system like WP isn't the best bet and likely not the best use of your time as far as learning goes. Don't use plugins for stupid crap like adding GA codes. Do use plugins for things like contact forms or anything that requires user input on WP.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out on my own. Had to wrap all the echo commands from tutorial in php